# React tree-shaking problem when function with object is return [Typescript + React + Rollup]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollup, tree-shaking

I spend a lot of time to make my library a little bit more tree-shakable but can't figure it out one particular problem.
I have multiple Icons components that look like this one:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

import createSvgIcon from '../utils/createSvgIcon';

export const Star = createSvgIcon(
    {
        regular: (
            <path d="M6.137 23.803L12 20.72l5.863 3.082c1.04.547 2.284-.332 2.082-1.512l-1.122-6.527 4.742-4.62c.852-.83.381-2.28-.794-2.45l-6.554-.955-2.93-5.94c-.524-1.059-2.045-1.072-2.574 0l-2.93 5.94-6.554.955c-1.175.17-1.646 1.62-.794 2.45l4.742 4.62-1.122 6.527c-.202 1.18 1.041 2.064 2.082 1.512zm11.44-2.584L12 18.289l-5.576 2.93 1.063-6.209-4.513-4.396 6.236-.906L12 4.055l2.79 5.653 6.236.906-4.513 4.396 1.063 6.209z" />
        ),
        solid: (
            <path d="M6.137 23.803L12 20.72l5.863 3.082c1.04.547 2.284-.332 2.082-1.512l-1.122-6.527 4.742-4.62c.852-.83.381-2.28-.794-2.45l-6.554-.955-2.93-5.94c-.524-1.059-2.045-1.072-2.574 0l-2.93 5.94-6.554.955c-1.175.17-1.646 1.62-.794 2.45l4.742 4.62-1.122 6.527c-.202 1.18 1.041 2.064 2.082 1.512z" />
        ),
    },
    'Star',
);
export default Star;
```

The createSvgIcon look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

import SvgIcon, { SvgIconProps } from '../components/SvgIcon';

interface CreateSvgIconTypes {
    /**
     * Regular path for this icon
     */
    regular?: React.ReactNode;
    /**
     * Solid path for this icon
     */
    solid?: React.ReactNode;
}

export interface ExtendedSvgIconProps extends Omit<SvgIconProps, 'children'> {
    /**
     * Solid version of this Icon (will throw an error if it doesn't exist)
     */
    solid?: boolean;
}

export default function createSvgIcon(
    { regular: regularPath, solid: solidPath }: CreateSvgIconTypes,
    displayName: string,
) {
    let Icon = SvgIcon;
    const Component = ({ solid, ...rest }: ExtendedSvgIconProps) => {
        if (!solidPath && !regularPath) throw new Error('There is no path specified for this icon');
        else if ((solid && !solidPath) || (!solid && !regularPath)) {
            throw new Error(
                `There is no ${displayName} of this type, please use one of those types :\n${
                    regularPath ? `- regular : <${displayName} />\n` : ''
                }${solidPath ? `- solid : <${displayName} solid/>\n` : ''}`,
            );
        }

        return <Icon {...rest}>{(solid && solidPath) || (!solid && regularPath)}</Icon>;
    };

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        // Need to set `displayName` on the inner component for React.memo.
        // React prior to 16.14 ignores `displayName` on the wrapper.
        Component.displayName = `${displayName}Icon`;
    }

    return React.memo(Component);
}
```

And this component is bundle like this in my esm.js bundle:

```js
const Star = createSvgIcon({
    regular: (createElement("path", { d: "M6.137 23.803L12 20.72l5.863 3.082c1.04.547 2.284-.332 2.082-1.512l-1.122-6.527 4.742-4.62c.852-.83.381-2.28-.794-2.45l-6.554-.955-2.93-5.94c-.524-1.059-2.045-1.072-2.574 0l-2.93 5.94-6.554.955c-1.175.17-1.646 1.62-.794 2.45l4.742 4.62-1.122 6.527c-.202 1.18 1.041 2.064 2.082 1.512zm11.44-2.584L12 18.289l-5.576 2.93 1.063-6.209-4.513-4.396 6.236-.906L12 4.055l2.79 5.653 6.236.906-4.513 4.396 1.063 6.209z" })),
    solid: (createElement("path", { d: "M6.137 23.803L12 20.72l5.863 3.082c1.04.547 2.284-.332 2.082-1.512l-1.122-6.527 4.742-4.62c.852-.83.381-2.28-.794-2.45l-6.554-.955-2.93-5.94c-.524-1.059-2.045-1.072-2.574 0l-2.93 5.94-6.554.955c-1.175.17-1.646 1.62-.794 2.45l4.742 4.62-1.122 6.527c-.202 1.18 1.041 2.064 2.082 1.512z" })),
}, 'Star');
```

And this is not tree-shaked! Even by adding `/*#__PURE__*/` manually. Every single icons are imported even if they are not used.

the original function is taken from material-ui: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/utils/createSvgIcon.js

And used like this :

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import createSvgIcon from './utils/createSvgIcon';

export default createSvgIcon(
  <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z" />
, 'Add');
```

I really think the main problem is that we use an object as parameter to createSvgIcon but I can't figure why.

Thanks for your help, I really spend a lot of time on this and can't find a way to fix it.